# Java: thread safe class instances

Tags: java

I have the following two classes:

```
public class MyClass {

   public static void faceTheWorld(String Input){
      SafeClass sC = new SafeClass();
      sC.workWithInput(Input);
   }
}

public class SafeClass {
   public void workWithInput{String allInp)

   work with allInp...
}
```

My question is. If I call MyClass.FaceTheWorld() several times at the very same time, will it always create a new class instance of SafeClass or will it try to create the same instance called 'sC' all the time?

Would I need to create an array of instances instead to make avoid creating the same instance at the same time? How would this look in Java?

Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve is that when I call FaceTheWorld with the 'Input' it would always make sure that 'Input' is thread safe e.g. no other instances can modify/access it.

I make SafeClass synchronized, would that solve the problem?

Many thanks

Comment: We would be happy to see following java naming conventions.

Comment: Hi Amit, what do you mean?

Comment: use camel case while writing method names and use pascal case while writing class names(you followed for class name)

Comment: Followed naming conventions suggested by Amit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will create a new instance every time, so it should be thread safe, barring any other weird things that you aren't telling us (like that object making use of static variables within the method you call).  But if you are afraid it will be using the same object on each call, it will not.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I'm now paranoid with this, so just to confirm again. Even though in the code we are creating a new instance 'sC', in the memory it will always be a different, new instance? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't access variables that can be changed by other threads (members of classes, or static variables) you will never have any race conditions if you just create a new instance in a static method (or any other method) because each method has its own stack of variables.

And to be concrete to your question:

It will always create a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

It will always create new instance no matter how often will you initialize it. Synchroznied keyword isn't solution to your problem.